# useSelector and UseEffect with dispatch functions create loop due to not updating state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, infinite-loop, dispatch

I am trying to develop a React application that shows a list of items using Hooks but an infinite loop is happening. I think the state is not being identified as updated but I cannot tell why.

I have seen at the documentation that it could be the dependencies that I should add on the useEffect function, **but when I remove the dependencies on useEffect it solves the problem.** Moreover this is not what the documentation recommends to do, they recommend to put all dependencies on the list.

The codesandbox is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-listing-forked-6sd99 and **if I uncomment the line 30 at `Dashboard.ts`** it is possible to see the infinite loop, this is the line that calls the `dispatch` function (and also codesandbox will freeze for some seconds).

The useSelector and useEffect functions are as below, located at the `Dashboard.tsx` file:

```
  const catalog = useSelector<RootState, MetricState>(
    (state) => state.fetchMetrics
  );
  console.log(catalog);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const classes = useStyles();
  useEffect(() => {
    // dispatch(appReducer.actionCreators.fetchMetrics());
  },[catalog, dispatch]));
```

The mocked data is as below, on the `apiCreators.js` file

```
export function fetchMetrics() {
  const action = {
    type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_METRICS,
    payload: []
  };
  return fetchMetricsCall(action);

const fetchMetricsCall = (action) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: action.type,
      payload: {
        metrics: [
          {
            name: "one",
            owner: {
              team: "test"
            }
          },
          {
            name: "one",
            owner: {
              team: "test"
            }
          }
        ] //contains the data to be passed to reducer
      }.metrics
    });
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({
      type: ACTION_TYPES.FAILURE,
      payload: console.log(e) //TODO: fix return type
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, I uncomment the line and the error doesn't arrises

Comment: Sorry, it was missing something, updating the code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is the `catalog` inside `[catalog, dispatch]` found here:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // dispatch(appReducer.actionCreators.fetchMetrics());
  },[catalog, dispatch]));
```

The issue is that `dispatch(appReducer.actionCreators.fetchMetrics())` is causing `state.fetchMetrics (aka catalog)` to update (which is an object), and javascript is "weird" when it comes to comparing objects/arrays.

So let's look at this:

```
let x = {a: 0}
let y = {a: 0}
let z = x

console.log(x === y) // this is FALSE
console.log(x === x) // this is TRUE
console.log(z === x) // this is TRUE
```

This article does a better job of going into it: http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html

`useEffect` is doing something like `if(oldState.catalog !== newState.catalog) {...rerender component}` whenever there's a change in state (I feel like this might be really inaccurate, but I hope it helps kind of illustrate what's going on). So the component rerenders and makes a new call to `dispatch`, which updates the state and since one of the dependancies inside `useEffect` is an object, it's impossible to make an update that will tell `useEffect` to "stop rerendering".

There are ways to work around this, but you shouldn't need the `catalog` inside the `[catalog, dispatch]`. Simply removing it seems to fix the issue?

Comment: yes, removing catalog it fix the issue but I was interested in knowing why, now I got it! Thank you for your explication and references! :)